# DNS resolves internal domain on server but on no other hosts

Tags: networking, dns

I have a DNS server on my network that holds a local zone. When I lookup domains in the zone from the server they resolve fine, i.e.

```
# nslookup internal.site 127.0.0.1
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   internal.site
Address: 192.168.1.200

# dig +short @127.0.0.1 internal.site
192.168.1.200
```

but from any other machine on the network they fail to resolve.

```
$ nslookup internal.site 192.168.1.10
Server:         192.168.1.10
Address:        192.168.1.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find internal.site: No answer

$ dig +short @192.168.1.10 internal.site
```

netstat reports the port is used by named

```
# netstat -tulpn | grep ":53 "
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1639/named          
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1639/named          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53               0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1639/named          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53               0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1639/named          
udp        0      0 192.168.1.10:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1639/named          
udp        0      0 192.168.1.10:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1639/named          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53               0.0.0.0:*                           1639/named          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53               0.0.0.0:*                           1639/named
```

And nmap reports the port is open

```
$ sudo nmap -sU -p53 10.0.0.10
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-03-05 19:11 EST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.10
Host is up (0.028s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/udp open  domain

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.15 seconds
```

Comment: check your named.conf.options, `allow-query` setting. does it allow your LAN IP range?

Comment: I tried setting it to `allow-query { any; };` but it didn't seem to have an affect, I should note I have `allow-recursion { any; };` and `recursion yes;` set